# AngularJs UI Grid rebind from Modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, data-binding, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-grid

I have a main controller in which I load data into a "angular-ui-grid" and where I use a bootstrap modal form to modify detail data, calling ng-dlbclick in a modified row template :

```
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $modal, $log, SubjectService) {
    var vm = this;    
    gridDataBindings();

    //Function to load all records
    function gridDataBindings() {
        var subjectListGet = SubjectService.getSubjects(); //Call WebApi by a service

        subjectListGet.then(function (result) {
            $scope.resultData = result.data;
        }, function (ex) {
            $log.error('Subject GET error', ex);
        });

    $scope.gridOptions = {                 //grid definition
        columnDefs: [
          { name: 'Id', field: 'Id' }
        ],
        data: 'resultData',
        rowTemplate: "<div ng-dblclick=\"grid.appScope.editRow(grid,row)\" ng-repeat=\"(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name\" class=\"ui-grid-cell\" ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }\" ui-grid-cell></div>"
    };

    $scope.editRow = function (grid, row) {                 //edit row 
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'ngTemplate/SubjectDetail.aspx',
            controller: 'RowEditCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
            resolve: {
                grid: function () { return grid; },
                row: function () { return row; }
          }
        });
    }
});
```

In the controller 'RowEditCtrl' I perform the insert/update operation and on the save function I want to rebind the grid after insert/update operation. This is the code :

```
app.controller('RowEditCtrl', function ($modalInstance, $log, grid, row,  SubjectService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.entity = angular.copy(row.entity);
    vm.save = save;

    function save() {
        if (vm.entity.Id === '-1') {
            var promisePost = SubjectService.post(vm.entity);
            promisePost.then(function (result) {
                //GRID REBIND  ?????      
            }, function (ex) {
                $log.error("Subject POST error",ex);
            });
        }
        else {
            var promisePut = SubjectService.put(vm.entity.Id, vm.entity);
            promisePut.then(function (result) {
                //row.entity = angular.extend(row.entity, vm.entity);
                //CORRECT WAY?
            }, function (ex) {
                $log.error("Subject PUT error",ex);
            });
        }
        $modalInstance.close(row.entity);
    }
});
```

I tried **grid.refresh()** or **grid.data.push()** but seems that all operation on the 'grid' parameter is undefinied.

Which is the best method for rebind/refresh an ui-grid from a bootstrap modal ?

Comment: where exactly r u trying to refresh the grid ?

Comment: Inside the save function of 'RowEditCtrl' controller, in the promise after post or put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved in this way:

In **RowEditCtrl**

```
            var promisePost = SubjectService.post(vm.entity);
            promisePost.then(function (result) {                
            vm.entity.Id = result.data;
            row.entity = angular.extend(row.entity, vm.entity);
            $modalInstance.close({ type: "insert", result: row.entity });
        }, function (ex) {
            $log.error("Subject POST error",ex);
        });
```

In **MainController**

```
 modalInstance.result.then(function (opts) {
        if (opts.type === "insert") {
            $log.info("data push");
            $scope.resultData.push(opts.result);
        }
        else {
            $log.info("not insert");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The **grid** that received inside **RowEditCtrl** is not by reference, so it wont help to refresh inside the **RowEditCtrl**.
Instead do it right after the modal promise resolve in your **MainController**.
 like this:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({ ...});

modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
      grid.refresh() or grid.data.push()
});
```

Comment: another option is to return the updated grid from RowEditCtrl to MainController as a parameter like you already do in $modalInstance.close(grid); and extract it in MainController modalInstance.result.then(function (result) { ...grid = result... });

Comment: I tried your approach but the grid.refresh or grid.data.push are **always undefined**. I also tried to call **gridDataBindings** function but seems that modal promise fires before the end of the function..     `modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
            gridDataBindings();
            //$scope.gridOptions.data.push(result);
        });`